# Wi-fi on an Intel NUC not loading

Tags: 14.04, wireless, intel-nuc

I am following [this process](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos) and have [pasted my script here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23347456/).

The hardware is an [Intel NUC5PPYH](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/nuc/nuc-kit-nuc5ppyh.html) and I have made sure the firmware is downloaded and present in `/lib/firmware`.

I have read `/var/log/boot.log` and I do not see anything of concern. The system runs fine and connects via wired eth0 but just no wireless. Bluetooth works, just not wireless LAN.

Does the pasted wireless info script provide the answer as to what my next step should be? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You lack the needed firmware:

> [    4.639432] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: no suitable firmware found!

First, verify that you have these two files; iwlwifi-7265D-13.ucode and iwlwifi-7265-13.ucode:

```
ls /lib/firmware | grep 7265
```

If so, we are going to make copies but rename them:

```
cd /lib/firmware
sudo cp iwlwifi-7265D-13.ucode  iwlwifi-3165-9.ucode
sudo cp iwlwifi-7265-13.ucode  iwlwifi-3165-13.ucode
```

Reboot. Your wireless should be working.

Comment: Eureka! Works great! Thank you for the help. I had the "-14" versions of the hardware as they seemed to be the most current. Was missing the "-13"'s